# Using Restet with Guice DI & GWT

Tags: java, rest, gwt, guice, restlet

I've got a fairly simple GWT app set up using GWT-RPC and Guice.  At the moment I'm serving two things, the GWT-RPC service and an applet that accepts uploads.  It looks something like this:

```
public class MyGuiceModule extends ServletModule {
@Override
protected void configureServlets() {
        serve("/path/to/service").with(MyGWTServiceImpl.class);
        serve("/path/to/upload").with(MyUploadServlet.class);
        //bunch of bindings follow...
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to serve restlet resources or a restlet application from the same application and configure them in my guice module rather than the web.xml.  Previously I've set up REST backed GWT apps using Restlet but it didn't use DI so I'm a bit lost as to how this should work.

eta: here's my web.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE web-app
      PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
      "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

  <web-app>

    <filter>
      <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
      <listener-class>com.whatever.MyGuiceBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Default page to serve -->
    <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>home.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

  </web-app>
```

***update***

This solves the problem, cheers!

```
    bind(ServerServlet.class).in(Singleton.class);
    Map<String,String> initParams = new HashMap<String,String>();
    initParams.put("org.restlet.application", "path.to.your.RestletApplication");
    serve("/api/*").with(ServerServlet.class,initParams);
```

***update2***

Finally went with a solution I adapted from http://hpehl.info/google-appengine-restlet-guice.html which allows me to using injection within my resources and a single line to bind in the guicemodule.

Comment: Could you provide your `web.xml` to get into your problem. I cannot imagine what exactly you want to setup.

Comment: At the moment, the web.xml simply loads a guiceContextListener.  Guice then delegates to the correct servlet (as configured in MyServletModule)  I'll add it to the above.  What I want to do it add a rest framework on a path (say /api) using the same method.  I think it's possible with jersey but I'd rather use restlet if possible.  Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restlet offers a Restlet -> Servlet adapter with the `org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet` class. You should bind this to the desired path, and let it know the name of your `Application` like this:

```
serve("/api/*").with(ServerServlet.class);
getServletContext().setAttribute(
    "org.restlet.application", "com.you.MyApplication");
```

Where `com.you.MyApplication` should be replaced with your actual implementation of the `org.restlet.Application` class.

Comment: Brill, cheers! Looks just what I was after.  Next stop will be to get DI working for the resource classes.

Comment: Yea, also you can setup you servlet. Instead `<init-param>` used in `web.xml` you can create `initParams = new HashMap<String,String>` and pass it into Servlet like `serve("/api/*").with(ServerServlet.class,initParams);`

Comment: Ok, so I've got it bound using guice bind(ServerServlet.class).in(Singleton.class); however, I'm getting 404s rather than the hello world I want :(

Comment: I've updated my OP with more details, if you've got any ideas that would be great.

Comment: Ok, fixed it!  you need to put the application in the initParams, not the servlet context.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Well, i tought you add your old web.xml. But this should solve your problem.

```
serve("/api/*").with(ApiServlet.class);
```

If you are not using plain Servlet as implementation of your REST api, it will be a bit tricky. Jersey can be integrated with Guice either.

Comment: This was what I was initially going to to do, insert a org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet just like that.  Unfortunately it can only be configured via web.xml or a separate restlet.xml file and I'd rather avoid that.  http://restlet.org/learn/javadocs/snapshot/gae/ext/org/restlet/ext/servlet/ServerServlet.html

Comment: However, your comment prompted me to look at the  org.restlet.ext.servlet package in more depth ann I've found ServletAdapter, which looks like it could do what I want.    So cheers!  http://restlet.org/learn/javadocs/snapshot/gae/ext/org/restlet/ext/servlet/ServletAdapter.html